# Custom css code in wordpress

Tags: css

Can someone maybe help me with a few lines of css code?

I would like to my search section on my page:

http://www.virtual-forms.com/docs/

To look something like this: https://docs.wedevs.com/

I would like to change this 3 elements (search-field (textbox), search_in_doc (combobox) and search-submit (button)). First to align them inline, and then to change the appearance to look like the one on this another page.

Thanks, Davor

Answer (score 1):

In general, you can change any CSS by adding your own 'customized CSS' to the theme; many themes have an option in the theme Customization to add CSS. If not, there are plugins available that will add that capability.

You can also create a Child Theme, and then add your custom css to that child theme's styles.css . You don't want to edit the theme's code, as any changes will get overwritten during a theme update.

As for actual CSS, perhaps you should start by learning CSS. A good basic tutorial is here: https://www.w3schools.com/css/default.asp . Information about Child Theme is in the WP Codex: https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes . Information about Customized CSS in a theme is here: http://www.wpbeginner.com/plugins/how-to-easily-add-custom-css-to-your-wordpress-site/ . The googles are a good place to find additional information.

Comment: Thanks @Rick I've tried a lot of combinations in custom css but obviously can't get the right class or div

Comment: I use the Developer tools (F12 in browser, although I use Firebug in Firefox) to find the exact CSS 'class' to modify. That allows you to make temporary changes and see them in the browser. Then you take that CSS and put it in your customized CSS. You may need to add the '!important' parameter to ensure that your change doesn't get overridden by a subsequent CSS class/id.